# does Android WebKit browser have the ability to start without UI, just the engine?

Tags: android, webkit

I am working on Android app that should simulate browser request, load reasons.
I have successfully recorded all the traffic on the device.
My question:
Could I start `WebKit` engine and send URL to start navigate, I doesn't need the response to be rendered or to see the browser at all?

Flow:

1. start WebKit engine without UI.
2. use WebKit API to start navigate.
3. get response saved in file/DB/or any other storage.

Is that Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends exactly what you want and what your requirements are.

If you want to just request a URL via HTTP and retrieve the result, you could use [`HttpGet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html%60).

If you want to simulate fetching a page, as a browser would - including fetching all images, stylesheets, scripts and other data on it - you could use an invisible [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Hi Dave, webview.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
give me the wanted solution, Thanks.